# Showing Product View Count on Woo commerce Product Page

Tags: php, wordpress

i have WordPress site www.kampungcourse.id to choose language program courses. i want to show how many people have watched particular product . using the post view counter plugin it show post view on home page and blog page but not on woo-commerce product pages. can anyone help with custom code to implement this

i tried using post view counter plugin but it does not work on product pages that are part of woo-commerce.

Comment: Please refer this woo commerce plugin on github for product view count  https://github.com/wp-plugins/product-view-counter

Answer (score 0):

Insert the below code into function.php file. you can insert view count on table by user IP address.

```
add_action('wp', function() {

global $post;

$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'views_count', TRUE );

$meta = '' !== $meta ? explode( ',', $meta ) : array();
$meta = array_filter( array_unique( $meta ) );

if( ! in_array( $user_ip, $meta ) ) {

array_push( $meta, $user_ip );
update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'views_count', implode(',', $meta) );
}
});
```

Display particular product view count before add to cart button.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_before_addtocart_button_func',0 );
function add_content_before_addtocart_button_func() {

        global $product;
        $id = $product->id;         
        $meta = get_post_meta( $id, 'views_count', TRUE );
        if(empty($meta))
        {
            $result = 0;
        }
        else
        {        
        $result = count(explode(',',$meta)); 
        }       
        echo "<div class='custom-visitor-count-st' style='font-size: 20px;'>";
        echo "<i class='fa fa-eye'></i>";
        echo "<span class='cv-value'>";
        echo $result;
        echo " Views</span></div>";
}
```

You can use any other woo commerce hook to display view count.

Comment: will it show total number of product watched by a perticular visitor. or total number of visit by all users. because i want to show total number of visits by all user,. so visitors can know how many times a product has been watched.

Comment: It will show total count of product watch by all user.

Comment: so i should add both code to function.php or just the second one

Comment: Add Both Code into function.php.

Comment: yehh. It will Works. You can Change design According as per your requirement in add_content_before_addtocart_button_func() function.

Comment: bro it is showing views next to the add to cart buttom on buttom part of page.  i want to show it on top of page next to rating bar. https://www.kampungcourse.id/program/arabic-full-day-1-bulan/ . like next to rating bar on this page. do you know where i should i edit to make that postion change?

Comment: @imrankhan You need to change woo commerce hook in this add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'add_content_before_addtocart_button_func',0 );

Comment: @imrankhan Please see My Another Answer to view price next to rating bar.

Answer (score 0):

Please Replace this function as below to show view on top of page next to rating bar.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_before_rating_button_func',0 );

    function add_content_before_rating_button_func() {        
                global $product;
                $id = $product->id;         
                $meta = get_post_meta( $id, 'views_count', TRUE );
                if(empty($meta))
                {
                    $result = 0;
                }
                else
                {        
                $result = count(explode(',',$meta)); 
                }       

        ?>
                <script>
                var html="";
                var result = "<?php echo $result ?>";
                html += "<div class='custom-visitor-count-st' style='font-size: 20px;'>";
                html += "<i class='fa fa-eye'></i>";
                html += "<span class='cv-value'>";
                html += result;
                html += " Views</span></div>";

                $(html).insertAfter('.woocommerce-product-rating');
                </script>
                <?php
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated hook for viewing view count on product page view
Let me know if this helped you out.

i will look and make revisions on this one.

Please next time do mention which theme you're using it helps to get answer faster.

```
add_action('wp', function() { // Adds a function to the 'wp' action hook

    global $post; // Retrieves the global $post variable

    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Retrieves the IP address of the user

    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'views_count', TRUE ); // Retrieves the 'views_count' metadata for the post

    $meta = '' !== $meta ? explode( ',', $meta ) : array(); // Splits the metadata into an array using comma as the delimiter, or creates a new array if the metadata is empty

    $meta = array_filter( array_unique( $meta ) ); // Removes any duplicate IP addresses from the array

    if( ! in_array( $user_ip, $meta ) ) { // Checks if the user's IP address is already in the array

        array_push( $meta, $user_ip ); // Appends the user's IP address to the array

        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'views_count', implode(',', $meta) ); // Updates the 'views_count' metadata for the post with the modified array, converting it back to a comma-separated string
    }
});
```