# Show View Count in single product page

Tags: woocommerce

I have e-commerce website where I would like people to see view count in Woocommerce single product page.

I tried this kind of code, but it only shows 1 view on every product that is wrong number.
Can you please help me?
Thank you in advance.
Here is a code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_content_func',0 );
function add_content_func() {

        global $product;
        $id = $product->id;         
        $meta = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_wcfm_product_views', true );
        if(empty($meta))
        {
            $result = 0;
        }
        else
        {        
        $result = count(explode(',',$meta)); 
        }       
        echo "<div class='custom-visitor-count-st' style='font-size: 20px;'>";
        echo "<i class='fa fa-eye'></i>";
        echo "<span class='cv-value'>";
        echo $result;
        echo " Views</span></div>";
}
```

P.S. I am using WCFM Marketplace. That's why I used this kind of meta to get product views: `get_post_meta( $product_id, '_wcfm_product_views', true );`

Comment: A quick google search shows that [you're not the first to ask this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57724071/showing-product-view-count-on-woo-commerce-product-page).  Please try to look for answers yourself before posting a question.